# How to populate 2 spinner based on selection of 1 spinner where data comes from server in android using volley?

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I am new to android and i want to make 3 spinner, 1 is to work, 2 is stain and 3rd is price. The data should come from server through JSON. If i select Metier example plumber then by selection of plumber i should get the list of tasks related to the plumber. . Price should get the price. The spinner should change according to 1st spinner.

Comment: post your code what ever you done.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do that give a network call on first spinner selection
for example:
if plumber is selected in first spinner post this string to server and get the data regarding this string "plumber"
after you get the data populate the data with second and third spinner
Hope its help :)

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            String items = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
           //Here give a network call
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: how ?? I make the connection in json then I call it ??

Comment: how can I do it I have not found an example please ??   });

Comment: like this ?? spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             employeename.setText(getemployeeName(position));
                String metier= arrayList.get(position);
                tacheename.setText(metier);
                getTaches();
            }@Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                employeename.setText("");
      }  });  }

Comment: does'nt work ` spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               employeename.setText(getemployeeName(position));
                String metier= arrayList.get(position);
                arrayListTache.clear();
              getTaches();
     }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                employeename.setText("");
    } });  }`